# Grails : Select returns (randomly) null while row exists in PostgreSQL with connection pooling turned on

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, connection-pooling

We develop a Grails 2.0 Application which formerly ran smoothly over MySQL

We've been asking by our admins to switch to PostgreSQL which they prefer

We've added a bunch of new features to the application, including the one that causes us problem now : asynchronous third-party webservice request

So, we have a domain object created, let's call it Question. With an `afterInsert` closure, a `Resource` is created, as to store at a later time the result of the call to the external webservice.

```
class Question implements Serializable {

    static hasMany = [resources: Resource]

    static constraints = {
        resources(nullable: true)
    } 
    def afterInsert() {
        Resource.withNewSession {
            Resource txt = Resource.create(null)
            this.addToResources(txt)
        }
    }           

    Resource retrieveResource(){
      return this.resources.find{ it instanceof Resource }
    }        

    static Question create(Map params) throws SaveDomainException {
        //question creation
    }    
}
```

We create the question like this :

```
//first we create question and save it
def question = Question.create(params)
question.save(flush:true, insert:true)
getThirdPartyService().doCallAsync((int)req.retrieveResource().id)
```

and the `ThirdPartyService` as a method `doCallAsync` which spawns an `ExecutorService` (obtained via the executors grails plugin so that this is not the dreaded "Hibernate Session - Thread" problem)
which executes a simple `Resource.get(res_id)` with the Id obtained as shown above

The problem is that with PostgreSQL and `pooled = true` in `DataSource.groovy`, the `get` returns sometimes null, sometinmes the resource object.

We have tested with 3 different requests : a `get(id)`, a `findById(id)`, and an `executeQuery` with a select.

The more weird is that with the three lines above in the same method, we have different results sometimes. Only one off the three returns null, or the three returns null, or none (which is the expected behavior, i recall)

We've turned on the PostgreSQL query logs to see if it was an Hibernate cache problem, but the 3 requests all appear in the logs, so hibernate hits each time the database. We see the insert of the resource with the correct id, followed by a commit, followed by the three selects (which are provided with the correct Resource Id)

Does anyone has a hint about what we gonna test further to see where this bug comes from ? (we tried to change connection pool, with no luck)

A last thing, if we add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` (which is gory but for testing purpose-only ;-) )before the requests, all runs smoothly. So, it seems to be a problem of visibility between postgres processes, but we don't have a clue about how to solve that

Answer (score 2):

You've taken the time to study this problem and write it up as a well presented question, but leave out the vital logs?

I'll speculate that you've got overlapping transactions between your save and the async get. Either the save hasn't committed or the get is seeing a consistent snapshot before the save occurs. Make sure you have process-id enabled in the logging, or some other way to distinguish connections and just see what order the statements occur in.

---

Edit: looks like transaction snapshot timings.

In PostgreSQL all statements are within a transaction (possibly implicit and lasting only one statement).

The default mode is "Read Committed" which means you can see commits that occur during your transaction.

There is also the option of a "serializable" level which means you (mostly) see a frozen snapshot of your database at the time of transaction start.

For more see [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

Open up two psql consoles and try out some variations on committing in one and selecting in the other with different isolation levels. You should be able to see what's happening with your live system.

Comment: Yeah, it sure sounds like a race condition where the `SELECT` is being run in a transaction which grabbed a snapshot before the save was actually acknowledged to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes we have process-id enabled in the logging and you are right. The `insert`+`commit` are executed in a different process of the three `select`. How can we check if the snapshots are synchronized ? Is it possible to force this synchronization ?

Comment: yes I saw it and tested it but we have another synchronisation problem. I search where is the problem and if I can get around it. I give you some news later .

Comment: Ok now after some tests, the problem is when we register so much Question. Sometimes `insert` fails with the message "Could not synchronize database state with session". I backed to the old config and I maked loop with a `select` followed by a `Thread.sleep('1000')`. The first iteration always fails and the second is always correct. I have no case with more 2 iterations. So as you say the problem is the snapshot when the select is executed. But in log and in the code the select is after the insert and if the `insert` fails we don't execute `select`. So why the insert isn't in the snapshot ?